# Problems getting the ID and redirecting the page to product-details

Tags: angular, firebase, angular5

I'm trying to redirect from the list of products to a product-details page, but my URL is duplicating some parts and getting a wrong Id.

example:

/cafe-c3c52.firebaseapp.com/admin/products/

when I click on button edit, the URL changes to /cafe-c3c52.firebaseapp.com/admin/products/%5B/admin/products/'%20,%20p.key%5D

admin-products.component.html

```
  <tbody>
<tr *ngFor= "let p of products$ | async">
  <td>{{p.title}}</td>
  <td>{{p.price}}</td>
  <td><a routerLink="['/admin/products/', p.key"> Edit</a> </tr>
  <td> {{p.key}}</td>
</tr>
```

admin-products-component.ts

```
 export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  products$;


  constructor(private productService: ProductService)  {
    this.products$ = this.productService.getAll();
  }
```

products.form.component

```
export class ProductsFormComponent implements OnInit {
  categories$;
  product;




  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService) {
      this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();

      const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');


      if (id) {


  this.productService.get(id).snapshotChanges().pipe(
      take(1)).subscribe(p => this.product = p);
      }
    }

}
```

product.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }



getAll() {
  return this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges().map(
    changes => {return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload, ...c.payload.val()}));
  });
}

get(productId) {
  return this.db.object('/products/' + productId);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close your `routerLink` in your anchor tag.

```
<td><a routerLink="['/admin/products/', p.key"> Edit</a> </tr>
```

add closing **]** and also around `routerLink`

```
<td><a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/', p.key]"> Edit</a> </tr>
```

Comment: You'll also need to add enclosing brackets => `[routerLink]=...`.

Comment: Awesome guys! thank you! Now I need to understand why the ID is showing "undefined"...